# Como realizar esta consulta en dql o querybuilder

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, doctrine2, doctrine

¿Cómo realizar esta consulta en *dql* o *querybuilder*?

```
select m.id, m.nombre, c.id, c.nombre from miembro as m
 inner join (
  select cmi.id_cargo, cmi.id_miembro, cmi.id from cargo__miembro as cmi
  inner join (
   select muc.id as idmiembro, Max(cmuc.id) as uid from miembro as muc 
   inner join cargo__miembro as cmuc on muc.id = cmuc.id_miembro
   inner join cargo as c1 on cmuc.id_cargo = c1.id
   group by muc.id
  )  as cm WHERE cmi.id = cm.uid
 )  as cm on m.id = cm.id_miembro
 inner join cargo as c on cm.id_cargo = c.id
```

*Estoy usando symfony 3*

Answer (score 0):

Existen ciertas consultas que simplemente no vas a poder hacer con DQL o QueryBuilder (al menos no, que yo sepa). Mi recomendación es hacerla tal cual la tienes, es decir:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$conn = $em->getConnection();
$query = "[colocas aqui tu query]";
$consulta = $conn->prepare($query);
$consulta->execute(); 
$queryResults = $consulta->fetchAll();
```

Con ésto ya podrías desplegar el resultado con un foreach en tu vista.

Comment: amigo copie y pegue exactamente ese codigo le inclui incluso una consultica basica:

   $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $conn = $em->getConnection();       $q="select m.id, m.nombre from miembro as m ";
        $consulta = $conn->prepare($q);
        $consulta->execute();
        $queryResults = $consulta->fetchAll();

y me devuelve NULL eso...

Comment: Tienes tu proyecto en github?. qué versión de php estás usando?.

Comment: No no lo tengo ahi pero podria compartirlo por dropbox o cualquier cosa...estoy usando php 7

Comment: Hablame por chat en: https://www.linkedin.com/in/edi-roberto-camas-vasquez-73015874/